# I'm using react-multi-select-component, and It works properly, Now I want to add an extra button which deletes every selected element in input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Here, I'm using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component 
If anyone needs codepen https://codesandbox.io/s/10xn41w767 
I'm trying to implement these without using document.getElementById(), Any idea!!
So I sharing my codepen link where I added a button so that when we click the button it just removes every item that we selected in the dropdown box.
Hope it clarifies my problems.
https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-react-dropdown-forked-w28re?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Please update your question. You should include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself. You can edit your question and add code in the editor with the `<>` button

Comment: Hey, @caramba, I have already edited and tried to describe my problem through codepen, please check these.